# Codeigniter Message: Call to undefined function random_string()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've face this following error An uncaught Exception was encountered

> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function random_string()
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\HerbalCebu\application\controllers\login.php
>
> Line Number: 128
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\HerbalCebu\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once,

When i want to generate an random strings where it will place as temporary password for a user

And here's my Controller

```
function forgot_password()
            {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailpass', 'emailpass', 'trim|required');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {

            $this->load->view('Login/modal_forgot');
            $this->load->view('CustTemplate/header');
            $this->load->view('Login/Login');
            $this->load->view('CustTemplate/footer');
            }else{
            $password = ('alpha', 8);
            $data = array('password'=>md5($password));
            $this->db->where('email',$this->input->post('emailpass'));

            $this->db->update('users',$data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','here is your new password: <mark>'.$password.'</mark><br> please login now and change the given password');
            redirect(base_url('login'));
            }
            }

            public function check_email($password)
            {
                $email = $this->input->post('emailpass');

                $result = $this->queries_login->get_email($email);

                if($result)
                {
                    return TRUE;
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('Check_email','The email you entered is not on the database');
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
```

And the model

```
public function get_email($email)
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('users');
            $this->db->where('email',$email);
            $this->db->limit(1);

            $query = $this->db->get();

            if($query ->num_rows()==1)
            {
                return $query->result();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you load the string helper you might be best to load the helper in the __construct area of controller.

Comment: Don't use md5 for passwords again very unsecured not suited for passwords

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really see it in use anywhere in your code (maybe here: `$password = ('alpha', 8);`?), but you should load the helper before calling the function via `$this->load->helper('string');` or autoloading it in `application/config/autoload.php`

If the error still persists make sure the file exists in `system/helpers/string_helper.php`.

---

As is constantly suggested whenever someone uses `md5` - you really shouldn't use it (as even recommended in the offical docs): http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

You could use the `password_hash` function verify with `password_verify`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php